# Strange issue with spark caching

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, dataframe, caching

We are using Spark 2.2.0. We have a 1.5 TB of data in a hive table. We have 80 node cluster where each node has about 512 GB RAM and 40 cores.

I am accessing this data using Spark SQL. With plain Spark SQL (without caching) simple command like getting distinct count of a particular column value takes about 13 sec. But when I run the same command after caching the table it takes more than 10 min. Not sure what is the issue?

```
export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2
spark-shell --master yarn --num-executors 40 --driver-memory 5g --executor-memory 100g --executor-cores 5
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 10)
val df = spark.sql("select * from analyticalprofiles.customer_v2")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
spark.time(spark.sql("select count(distinct(household_number)) from tmp").show())
>> Time taken: 13927 ms



import  org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
val df2 = df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp2")
spark.time(spark.sql("select count(distinct(household_number)) from tmp2").show())
>> 1037482 ms ==> FIRST TIME - okay if this is more
spark.time(spark.sql("select count(distinct(household_number)) from tmp2").show())
>> 834740 ms  ==> SECOND TIME - Was expecting much faster execution ???
```

Tried samething with "spark.catalog.cacheTable("tmp")" but still with caching Query takes more time. Not sure why ??? Can somebody help ???

```
df2.storageLevel.useMemory
res6: Boolean = true

sc.getPersistentRDDs
res8: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map(12 -> In-memory table tmp MapPartitionsRDD[12] at cacheTable at <console>:24)

spark.conf.get("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed")
res11: String = true

spark.conf.get("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize")
res12: String = 10000

spark.catalog.isCached("tmp")
res13: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Can you check number of partitions ? I would like to check if it is overspilling from the memory and trying to write it in the disk ? if so, the time taken  could be due to the I/O involded for write.

Comment: Seems many are facing such issues. No guarantee all can be kept plus I assume the cluster is a shared resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

1. You can increase the number of executors and decrease the executor memory with the below formula

   ```
     SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES (--executor-cores) : 5 

     Number of Executors (--num-executors) : (number of nodes) *  (number of cores) /(executor cores) -1 (for Application Master) = (80*40)/5 ~ 640-1 = 639

     SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY (--executor-memory): Memory/(Number of Executors/Number of Nodes):  512/(639/80) ~ 64 GB
   ```
2. If you want to persist the dataframe use StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER . If the Memory (RAM) is full , it will save in Disk.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both MEMORY_ONLY and MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER. With MEMORY_ONLY it was caching only 18% of data but when I used MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER it cached 100% - with 18% in memory and remaining on disk. But I found one more problem. The size of my data on disk is around 1.5 TB (in Parquet format), but when I read it using Sparks MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER option it occupies around 11 TB (2 TB in memory and 9 TB on disk). Why is this so? I thought Serialised data will occupy less space when cached? Is there any way to compress cached data or at least make it occupy less space in memory/disk?